# Echo make my Makefile relink on every Make

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm working on a Makefile that i can use on most of my school projects.

I only did basics makefile before and never had a problem, but for this one i wanted to put some colors etc...
And it relink everytime i make it.

I think the relink come from my echos ? But i'm not sure.
Here is my makefile :

```
#GENERAL
CC = clang++
FLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++98
RM = rm -rf

#PROJET
EXEC = ClapTrap

#FILES
SRCS = ClapTrap.cpp main.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
OBJSDIR = objects/

#REGLES
.cpp.o: $(SRCS)
    mkdir -p $(OBJSDIR)
    echo "$(BLUE)Compiling $^ ..$(CLEAR)"
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $(addprefix $(OBJSDIR), $@)
    echo "   $(YELLOW)$(addprefix $(OBJSDIR), $@)$(CLEAR) [$(GREEN)OK$(CLEAR)]"

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    echo "$(BLUE)========================================$(CLEAR)"
    echo "$(BLUE)       Compiling binary file ..$(CLEAR)"
    echo "$(BLUE)========================================$(CLEAR)"
    $(CC) -o $(EXEC) $(addprefix $(OBJSDIR), $^) $(FLAGS)
    echo "$(YELLOW)$(EXEC)$(GREEN) is now ready to use !$(CLEAR)"

clean:
    @$(RM) $(OBJSDIR)
    @echo "$(RED)Cleaning up..$(CLEAR)"

fclean: clean
    @$(RM) $(EXEC)
    @echo -n "$(RED)$(EXEC)$(CLEAR)"

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all
```

Thank's for reading !

EDIT :

So i removed SRCS from my .cpp.o rules dependencies, but still relinking.
Here the updated Makefile :

```
#FILES
SRCS = ClapTrap.cpp main.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
OBJSDIR = objects

#REGLES
.cpp.o:
    echo "$(BLUE)Compiling $(YELLOW)$^$(BLUE) ..$(CLEAR)"
    mkdir -p $(OBJSDIR)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    mv $@ $(OBJSDIR)
    echo "$(BLUE) - $(YELLOW)$@$(CLEAR) [$(GREEN)OK$(CLEAR)]"

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    echo "$(BLUE)========================================$(CLEAR)"
    echo "$(BLUE)       Compiling binary file ..$(CLEAR)"
    echo "$(BLUE)========================================$(CLEAR)"
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(STD) $(addprefix $(OBJSDIR)/, $(OBJS)) -o $(EXEC)
    echo "$(YELLOW)$(EXEC)$(GREEN) is now ready to use !$(CLEAR)"
```

Comment: Your prerequisite for `$(EXEC)` is `$(OBJS)`, which doesn't contain your `OBJSDIR` prefix (and also transforms `x.cpp -> x.o`). Since these presumably don't exist the rule will always be out of date. Also your `.cpp.o:` rules should probably be something like `$(OBJSDIR)/%.cpp.o:` or similar.

Comment: This is wrong: `.cpp.o: $(SRCS)`.  It's not legal to have a list of prerequisites on a suffix rule: by adding the prerequisites you're changing this into a normal rule that builds the target named `.cpp.o`.  Even if it were legal to list prerequisites, this would be wrong: this says "every `.o` file depends on _all_ the `$(SRCS)` files", so if any one source file changes than all object files are considered out of date, and rebuilt.

Comment: Hey guyz thanks for your answers ! I deleted the dependancies on my sources for my .cpp.o rules but i still relink, i edit the post to show the modifications. Tried too the $(OBJSDIR)/.cpp.o: rules but clang tell me "no input file".

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
$(CC) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
mv $@ $(OBJSDIR)
```

When make runs your recipe it will put the file it expects you to build into the `$@` automatic variable.  If your makefile builds some OTHER file, not the one it asked you to build, then the next time you run make it will see that the file it wants doesn't exist (because you didn't build it, you build some *other* file) and so it's always out of date.

Your rules must always build exactly the file `$@`, not some other file.

It's not actually possible to write a makefile that puts targets in a different directory, using [suffix rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html).  They can only create files in the same directory.  That's (one reason) why GNU make supports [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) which are much more flexible.

If you have to write a POSIX conforming makefile that doesn't support pattern rules, and you want to put the object files in some other directory, all you can do is write out all the targets and their rules explicitly.